# View(Using XIB) does not Positioned in Bottom for Screen using Autolayout

Tags: ios, layout, screen, autolayout, xib

I have to add a View in `XIB` and placed it in bottom using `Autolayout` as in attached image. But not working its' showing fine in 3.5 and there is gap in 4" screen. Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing many tricks I got the answer, while I am adding this view in viewDidLoad where I have `XIB` of 4" Screen.

```
ActionView *view =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActionView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
view.frame  =self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

and constraints like

[image]

Even I still want to know why XIB is hungry about it's superview frame?? if any one know please, put some line here, otherwise I will come with reason once I will get that.

Comment: It maybe one of these options http://take.ms/ZgDLr at `ViewController`. I mean `bottom bar` select and `under bottom bar` checkbox.

Comment: No, Actually we need to tell the right view size for autolayout constraints calculation.